# How do I determine mitered angle for a four sided pyramid made from plywood? (USA)

Tags: woodworking

How do I make a four-sided pyramid out of plywood with mitered edges so that when assembled and painted you don't see the side edges of the wood? Does the angle of the mitered edge change depending on what the dimensions will be ? For a specific example, say I want to make a pyramid shape where the bottom of each side measures 12" wide and the total height at the apex measures 24", do I still miter cut the edges at 45 degrees or will this angle change depending on the size of the pyramid?

Comment: All those fun things at school with geometry come to mind... The Ancients were able to sort the angle of the pyramid sides to make the ratio between the base perimeter and the height to be equal to pi...

Comment: Also, check on here for a similar post about making pyramids - sure I read one with answers / suggestions.

Comment: If each corner is a perfect 90 degrees, then 45 degree cut will work.  This is usually easier on small projects than on house walls.  The cut line measurement does need to be exact and will probably want a power saw with a table and a jig for repeat cuts, than trying with hand saws.

Comment: @crip659 There's more to it. When the pyramid is very short compared to its base the angle between facets is very wide, approaching 180 degrees (think of a sheet of paper "tented" slightly). When the pyramid is infinitely tall compared to its base the angle between facets approaches 90 degrees (it looks a lot like a square tube). Only in that latter case will a 45 degree cut at the joint between facets fit "almost" right.

Comment: The edge cut at   45 remains

Comment: The very top point will probably need a compound/ or two cuts mitre cut.  A small solid block of wood for the top might be easier to make.

Comment: It will *not* be 45 degrees and the correct answer appears to involve some not so trivial trigonometry.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it really doesn't seem to be a home improvement project. It might not be a bad fit for the Woodworking stack.

Comment: I've got to admit, I didn't catch this before. I wonder if there's a difference in the angles if the pyramid is built in (USA) vs say (UK) or (AUS)...

Answer (score 4):

The miter angle varies with height to width ratio. 90 degrees is the miter angle in the limit as the pyramid height goes to zero. 45 degrees is the miter angle in the limit as the pyramid height goes to infinity.

My solution strategy is to treat the intersection of two pyramid faces as an axis, and measure the angle between faces when rotating about this axis. Half that angle is the miter angle.

For a pyramid sitting in the XY plane, put a base corner on the origin, and align it in the 1st quadrant so that vectors (w,0,0) and (0,w,0) provide two base *edges* of the pyramid. The *diagonal* going up from the origin to the apex is (w/2,w/2,h):

```
e1 = (w,0,0)
e2 = (0,w,0)
d = (w/2,w/2,h)
```

Orthogonally projecting a base edge vector onto the plane perpendicular to the pyramid's diagonal provides another vector that is perpendicular to the face-intersection-axis and still in the same face of the pyramid. Doing this operation for both `e1` and `e2` provides both the start and end of the rotation that we're looking to halve:

```
P = I - d⊗d/(d·d)
v1 = P·e1
v2 = P·e2
```

With the start vector and the end vector in hand, I use the dot product's geometric definition to find the angle between them:

```
theta = arccos(v1/sqrt(v1·v1) · v2/sqrt(v2·v2))
```

Finally I halve this angle to find the miter angle, `theta/2`.

Excel does matrix operations, where that might be the best place to do the computation. A symbolic engine (MatLAB or Octave or probably Mathematica or probably Maple) could give you a single expression, though, if you're desperate for one.

Here's an Octave session solving your example:

```
w = 12;
h = 24;
e1 = [w,0,0]';
e2 = [0,w,0]';
d = [w/2,w/2,h]';
P = eye(3) - d*d'/(d'*d);
v1 = P*e1;
v2 = P*e2;
theta = acosd(v1'/sqrt(v1'*v1) * v2/sqrt(v2'*v2));
theta/2
  ans = 46.686
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the "dihedral angle" between two faces of the square pyramid. I've tried to find a solution based in simple geometry but it's challenging! A solution using vectors (cross and dot products) for a slanted pyramid is described on math.SE [angle between faces of a pyramid](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2778217). There's an interesting [pyramid angle calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/pyramid-angle) at omni calculator, but alas, it does not show the dihedral angle.

I'll assume that you're interested in building what I'll call a balanced pyramid, which has its apex vertically above the center point of the base square.

Visualize your pyramid in an (x,y,z) coordinate system (sorry, I can't take time to draw a figure for it today). Put the vertices of the square base at A=(0,0,0), B=(12,0,0), C=(12,12,0), D=(0,12,0) and the peak at P=(6,6,24). Vector PA is calculated by finding the difference between points P and A, meaning the change in x, change in y, and change in z. So PA=(-6,-6,-24). Likewise PB=(6,-6,-24) and PC=(6,6,-24).

Khan academy can teach vector cross product and dot product far better than I could ever hope to do. Following along with that math.SE linked earlier, vector v= PA x PB = (0,-288,72) and w= PB x PC = (288,0,72).

Again referring to the math.SE post, the dihedral angle is cos<sup>-1</sup> (v ⋅ w)/(|v||w|). If I've done my math right it works out to 86.6 degrees for the pyramid sizes you've given.

The miter angle would be half the dihedral angle: 43.3 degrees. I think that's what I'd use to set the table saw angle for cutting the miter. The other angles for the corners of the sheet are conveniently shown in the omni calculator.

You could compute the miter angle between the base and the sides in a similar fashion. As, um, an exercise left for the reader. ;-)

Comment: For the limiting case of zero height, your algorithm outputs a miter angle of 0 degrees. It's easy to check, because everything fits into 2 dimensions (except the cross products, but they're at least normal to the page). Both cross products are aligned, therefore the normalized dot product reduces to 1, therefore arccos(1) = 0 ≠ 90. You computed the angle between the plane normals, not the planes. The miter angle would be (180 - 86.6)/2, assuming that your vector algebra is correct.

Comment: Oops. It's `≠ 180`.